# OAuth2 - Allow third party servers access protected API

Tags: oauth, keycloak, openid-connect, identity-management

I'm having an IAM (Keycloak) setup for SSO on my multiple first-party apps. Let's assume one of the first-party apps is **Stock Manager**. This app has an API server where a user can CRUD SKUs and products. Each *product* can have a name, description, *sku*, price, etc.

Then there is a third-party app **SuperAwesomeManager** which is just a server that has a cronjob running to fetch data of multiple users from **Stock Manager**.

The situation is I want to allow a **SuperAwesomeManager** only to access products with a *sku* as MY_PROD_SKU_1. How this can be achieved using keycloak as IAM? Just remember **SuperAwesomeManager** is running on a server and doesn't provide any UI and also can't share user credentials with **SuperAwesomeManager**.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create a confidential client for SuperAwesomeManager. The cron job will get an access token by logging into the confidential client with the clientid and secret, then call the API on Stock Manager using the access token.

You can use a mapper to add a claim to the access tokens created by the confidential client which indicates the token only has access to MY_PROD_SKU_1. Your API on Stock Manager must look for said claim in the access token and act accordingly.